# sqlcmd runs at command prompt, not as .bat

Tags: sqlcmd

I found a few threads related to this issue, but can't seem to find an answer that works.
I am using sqlcmd to create a .csv from a SQL table.  I would like this to run as a scheduled task, and have had success in the past using sqlcmd code in a .bat file.

My syntax:
sqlcmd -S SERVERNAME -d DATABASE -U sa -P PASSWORD -q "select * from TABLE" -o "C:\Export\sqlexport.csv" -s","

When I paste this code into the Command Prompt, it runs perfectly.

I then copy the code and save it with Notepad as a .bat file. When I run the batch, either from the Command Prompt or by double-click, it errors:
"Login failed for user 'sa'.

I am not understanding the reason for the different outcomes, nor have a found a solution after many hours of searching.  I'm sure its simple, but I'm new to this sqlcmd process.  I appreciate any advice!